# SharePoint C# recursive team site look up

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, web-parts

I developed a webpart to return all the site collections and webs that a user has read access to; I want to limit the results to Team sites only.

How can I accomplish this? I've looked through the applicable attributes, but am unable to determine which one will only return team sites.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following properties of [SPWeb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.aspx) could be used to determine the site template(definition):

- [WebTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.webtemplate.aspx) - the name of the site definition or site template
  that was used to create the site
- [WebTemplateId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.webtemplateid.aspx) - the identifier (ID) of the site definition that
  was used to create the site
- [Configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.configuration.aspx) - the identifier (ID) of the site definition
  configuration that was used to create the site, or the ID of the site
  definition configuration from which the site template used to create
  the site was derived

### Example

The following method is used to determine if site is Team Site:

```
private static bool IsTeamSite(SPWeb web)
{
     return (web.WebTemplate.Equals("STS",StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) && web.WebTemplateId == 1 && web.Configuration == 0);
}
```